# Fourier Result on Time Series explained python

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, fft, transformation

I have passed my time series data,which is essentially measurements from a sensor about pressure, through a Fourier transformation, similar to what is described in https://towardsdatascience.com/fourier-transform-for-time-series-292eb887b101.
The file used can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MLETSU5Trl5gLGO6pv32rxBsR8xZNkbK/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110574180158524908052&rtpof=true&sd=true
The code related is this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file='test.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(file,header=0)
#df=pd.read_csv(file,header=0)
df.head()
df.tail()
# drop ID
df=df[['JSON_TIMESTAMP','ADH_DEL_CURTAIN_DELIVERY~ADH_DEL_AVERAGE_ADH_WEIGHT_FB','ADH_DEL_CURTAIN_DELIVERY~ADH_DEL_ADH_COATWEIGHT_SP']]
# extract year month 
df["year"] = df["JSON_TIMESTAMP"].str[:4]
df["month"] = df["JSON_TIMESTAMP"].str[5:7]
df["day"] = df["JSON_TIMESTAMP"].str[8:10]
df= df.sort_values( ['year', 'month','day'],
          ascending = [True, True,True])
df['JSON_TIMESTAMP'] = df['JSON_TIMESTAMP'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.sort_values(by='JSON_TIMESTAMP', ascending=True)
df1=df.copy()
df1 = df1.set_index('JSON_TIMESTAMP')
df1 = df1[["ADH_DEL_CURTAIN_DELIVERY~ADH_DEL_AVERAGE_ADH_WEIGHT_FB"]]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (25,8)
df1.plot()
#df.plot(style='k. ')
plt.show()
df1.hist(bins=20)
    from scipy.fft import rfft,rfftfreq

## https://towardsdatascience.com/fourier-transform-for-time-series-292eb887b101

# convert into x and y
x = list(range(len(df1.index)))
y = df1['ADH_DEL_CURTAIN_DELIVERY~ADH_DEL_AVERAGE_ADH_WEIGHT_FB']

# apply fast fourier transform and take absolute values
f=abs(np.fft.fft(df1))

# get the list of frequencies
num=np.size(x)
freq = [i / num for i in list(range(num))]

# get the list of spectrums
spectrum=f.real*f.real+f.imag*f.imag
nspectrum=spectrum/spectrum[0]

# plot nspectrum per frequency, with a semilog scale on nspectrum
plt.semilogy(freq,nspectrum)
nspectrum
type(freq)
freq= np.array(freq)
freq
type(nspectrum)
nspectrum = nspectrum.flatten()
# improve the plot by adding periods in number of days rather than  frequency
import pandas as pd
results = pd.DataFrame({'freq': freq, 'nspectrum': nspectrum})
results['period'] = results['freq'] / (1/365)
plt.semilogy(results['period'], results['nspectrum'])
# improve the plot by convertint the data into grouped per day  to avoid peaks
results['period_round'] = results['period'].round()
grouped_day = results.groupby('period_round')['nspectrum'].sum()
plt.semilogy(grouped_day.index, grouped_day)
#plt.xticks([1, 13, 26, 39, 52])
```

My end result is this :
[Result of Fourier Trasformation for Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzsTn.png)

My question is, what does this eventually show for our data, and intuitively what does the spike at the last section mean?What can I do with such result?
Thanks in advance all!

Comment: I feel like this is a bit off topic for the site, especially since there is no relevant code provided. It would be easier to analyse if you provided your original data and your code for the transform. Because honestly from the looks of this FFT your data could just as well be random noise, as there are no leading frequencies visible.

Comment: Your transformed data looks wrong (it may be right, but it would be very surprising). If you share the data and the code you used, we can help you.

Comment: Please, check the updated post.!thanks for your comments!